# Transfering rows between tables on different database servers

Tags: sql, database

Say I have 2 database servers, and I want to transfer specific rows from tableA on server 1 to tableA on server2.

Is there any crossplatform (MySQL, Postgres etc.) solution for this problem?

Comment: In general you can search for ETL (extract transform load) software.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [Server2].[SchemaName].[TableA] ([Column1],[Column2],...)
SELECT [Column1],[Column2],...
FROM [Server1].[SchemaName].[TableA]
WHERE [YourConditions]
```

Which means data is selected from Server1 and inserted into Server2.

Let say there is a tableA on Server1:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tableA (priKey BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(50), Value INT)
INSERT INTO dbo.tableA (Name,Value) VALUES ('John',1),('Maria',4),('Steve',10)
```

and there is the same tableA (same table structure) on Server2, but the table is empty on Server2.

To transfer data from Server1 to Server2:

```
INSERT INTO Server2.dbo.TableA (Name,Value)
SELECT Name,Value
FROM Server1.dbo.TableA
```

Comment: Vitaly, please add some explanation of the code or they will downvote you :)

Comment: Huh.. added some explanation. I hope it does make sense.

Comment: What your code does is different databases, not different servers, and only works for SQL Server anyway.